# Let $x>0$. Prove that if $0<a<b$, then $(ae^{-bx} )-(be^{-ax})>a-b$.

Tags: calculus

This question is killing me and I need a detailed explanation with work on how to prove this.

Comment: What is the derivative of the left-side with respect to $x$?  Is it always positive for positive $x$?

Comment: Please put the problem statement in the question itself, and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is how the question was handed to me. I factored out the a and b respectively but I do not see how that will prove it.

Comment: I found that the derivative is (-abe^-bx) +(abe^-ax)

Comment: So, factoring, we have $ab(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})$ and we know $ab$ is positive.  Is $e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}$ for all positive $x$?  If it is positive for all positive $x$, what does that tell us noting that for $x=0$ we have $ae^{-bx}-be^{-ax}=a-b$

Comment: Which can written $ab(e^{-ax} - e^{-bx})$. What can you say ?

Comment: But wait isn't it -ab((e^-bx) -(e^-ax))? since its there is a -a in the derivative?

Comment: I think I see what you did now JMoravitz you switched the e to proper form thus why you got that sorry it took me a second to realize it.

Comment: And yeah since x>0 which means x is positive then e^{-ax}-e^{-bx} for all x>0. But why equal?

Comment: You guys are awesome thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

$x>0$ and $0<a<b \implies -ax>-bx$

$\implies e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}>0.$

thus the function $f: x\mapsto ae^{-bx}-be^{-ax}$ is strictly increasing at $(0,+\infty)$.

observe that $f(0)=a-b$ and conclude.